# How do I check if a facebook account is currently logged in before requesting permission for my app? (using php sdk)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the php sdk v3.0.1.
I am trying to get offline access from users.

When my app requests permission from the user, it does so for the currently logged in user.  I'd like to first check if a facebook account is logged in, and if so display a message.  for example:

User "John Doe" is currently logged in.

then I'd have a link to "log out" or a link to continue to the permission page.

I was trying this but it always returns 0:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXX',
  'secret' => 'YYYYYYYYY',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user)...
else...
```

the if statement always fails and then when the else is procesed and I send them to the login page, it requests permission for the currently logged in user (which I don't want).

I've searched extensively and can't find an answer.  :-/ Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm completely new to the facebook api.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would like authentication and permission requests to be separate. Correct me if I'm wrong about that. So you can just send users through a plain authentication step:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
```

and then later send them through again with the proper permissions.

```
$arg['req_perms'] = "[permissions here]";
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($arg);
```

This will get you a separate login and permission request step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't solve the problem.  I was already using that acutlly.  this is in my code:

if (!$user) 
{
    $args['scope'] = 'offline_access';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
    
    echo("<a href='{$loginUrl}'>Login with the Facebook account you wish to monitor</a>");
}

Comment: the problem is that $user is always 0, even if a user is logged in to facebook, and so when I navigate to $loginUrl, permission is requested from the wrong user who is already logged in.  I need to be able to find out (if possible) the name of the currently logged in user before requesting permission.  Is that possible?  that way they have the option of logging out so that permission isn't requested from the wrong user.

Comment: One thing I would recommend is updating to the most recent version of the Facebook php SDK. If $user is 0 from your code that means that the user isn't logged in. You said: "permission is requested from the wrong user who is already logged in" I don't know what you mean by "wrong user" -- I'm pretty confused whats going on.

Comment: I want to make sure when I request permission for my app to have access, that I'm requesting it from the correct user.  If John sit's down at the computer and goes to my site, but his brother Fred left his facebook account logged in, when my website requests permission, it will be requesting permission for Fred (not John).  I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: In the above case $user returns 0 even though Fred is logged in.

I'd like to have a message like "Fred is currently logged into facebook, click to log him out, or click here to request permission for my app to have access to your facebook account"

Comment: Got it. So $user is going to be whatever user is logged into Facebook on that computer right? There's no way to detect that somebody new has say down at the computer. I think your only option would be to prompt the user "Are you Fred?" if not then go to the logout url and then the login url. I want to point out that $user = 0 isn't a valid uid for facebook.

Comment: Yup! :)  what you said is exactly what I want.  But $user = $facebook->getUser();   is returning 0 when i try to check if someone is logged in so that I can ask if they are Fred or not.  So when my script sees the 0 it assumes (incorrectly) that nobody is logged in.  How can I detect that Fred is logged in?

Comment: Your problem is definitely that the $user is 0. It seems that there is something wrong with the authentication flow for your app. You should get a proper $user (non-zero) and then be able to prompt the user if they are Fred or not.

Comment: I'm at a a loss.  there isn't much code there.  All I do is include  php sdk v3.0.1 (which I believe is the current version), instantiate a facebook object (with my app id and secret) and then call $facebook->getUser() which returns zero no matter what.  :-/

Comment: do you ever redirect the user to the getLoginURL() ?

Comment: yes.  that's the url that I use for requesting permission.  When a user navigates to that url it goes directly to requesting permission for the currently logged in user without prompting for credentials.